# how to write task information in the spring data flow UI manually

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I integrate spring batch into a restful controller of a spring boot, which means now we operate spring batch program by send a restful call. In this case, we cannot make a jar and register the jar on spring data flow server. So my question is that how to register a task if we don't have jar

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a few similar questions today.

My recommendation is that you could consider referring to the ref. guide of Spring Cloud Task and Spring Cloud Data Flow. Specifically, pay attention to the [Spring Batch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#batch) section.

Once you have the understanding as to what to do, you can build a batch-job as a Spring Cloud Task application, and run it standalone successfully.

If it runs locally as expected, you can switch to SCDF and [register the JAR](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.7.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-register-stream-apps) using the [REST-API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.7.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#resources-app-registry-post), Shell, or in the GUI. You'd need a physical uber-jar of the application for it. With that registered, you can then build a Task definition with it, and launch it from SCDF.

If you want to do all of the above programmatically, please have a look at the [acceptance-test suite](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-acceptance-tests) for examples.